# How to fix "Could not autowire. No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found."?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using `JavaMailSender` but when I autowire it, it shows that No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found

I have imported it's class

`import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;`

Inside `SomeClass` (the class in which I am autowiring JavaMailSender):

```java
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-email: *If spring.mail.host and the relevant libraries (as defined by spring-boot-starter-mail) are available, a default JavaMailSender is created if none exists.*

Comment: please check have you specified the below properties 
spring.mail.host=smtp.xxx.com
spring.mail.username=xxx@xxx.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true

Comment: @AnuranjanBose can you accept the answers if it solve your issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

please check have you specified the below properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.xxx.com
spring.mail.username=xxx@xxx.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

Comment: Not a very intuitive "error" message.

Comment: For me it actually was only "spring.mail.host" that resolved the error.

Comment: even after specifying the properties, Intellij still giving me the red line with the message of  "No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found"  :/

Comment: in come cases  you'll need to configure a bean of it, so you can use it, check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039692/intellij-show-could-not-autowire-no-beans-of-javamailsender-type-found-whi)