# intellij show “Could not autowire. No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found.” while code still run correctly

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to autowire JavaMailSender

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
```

I have add these to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and these to application properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=xxx
spring.mail.password=xxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

and the project run correctly (i successed send a mail). but intellij show error on javaMailSender variable. and when i hover my mouse to the error it show

> "Could not autowire. No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found."

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I could not reproduce. Make sure the [Spring Application Context is configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#spring-file-set) in the Spring facet. If application function correctly as expected but IDE still shows the error report bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project attached.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a bean for Javamailsender. If my guess is right, you have a spring security in your dependencies.

You can do it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername("my@gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPassword("mypassword");

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }
}
```